# Extract words from text having length more than N characters - RegExp/Java/Android

Tags: java, android, regex

My first requirement was to extract all words from some text using regular expression in Java.

Following code is doing it perfectly for me

```
String[] words = text.split("[^\\w']+");
```

It also removes all punctuations and special characters except apostrophe(`'`)

My next task is to **extract words has more than (say) `3` characters, and importantly, I want to do this in above mentioned regular expression.**

*You might come up with some other regular expression which can do both of these tasks.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fun fact**. A `word` is a single distinct element of speech or writing to form a sentence and typically shown with a space on either side. `\w` matches (any `letter`, `number` or `underscore`)

It is unclear to exactly what you are asking without a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

If you want to match a word that contains `letters` and apostrophe `'` with **more** than `3` characters..

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
String s  = "I want to have alot of money's when I am older.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z']{4,}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  words.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(words);

// [want, have, alot, money's, when, older]
```

**Note**: This matches a word that contain's more than `3` characters, if you also want to match a word that contains `3` characters (`foo`) or more, you can use the following.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z']{3,}");
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `{3,}` changed to `{4,}` ? As it seems he wants words with more then 3 so at least 4 characters.

Comment: Yea that would be better probably.

Comment: Tried that too and came up with about the same, as any other solution, that I tried, complicates it. Especially if only using `split`.

Comment: @Jonny5 it get's complicated but you would have to use multiple assertions to split.

Comment: +1 for the perfect answer...